# is it possible to fold markdown preview when folding sections in editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I would like to use VS Code for markdown editing.

It is great that VS Code editor allows folding of text by indentation and by headings.

My question is whether it is possible (through a plugin say) to have the side-by-side markdown preview window to also fold the text that is folded in the editor and unfold when editor unfolds?

Thank you!

Comment: markdown preview is an extension, you can change the source code

Comment: thanks for your comment @rioV8. way beyond my skills today. this was more a question as to whether it is possible. if not, I will learn to live without it or hope to come across another software that can already do it.

Comment: I'd love this. Markdown is great for quickly creating presentations. Using folding I can hide/reveal text and code for dramatic effect. It would look better if folding worked in Preview. I upvoted the Vscode issue found my Thrastylon, so hopefully it'll happen!

Answer (score 5):

[It just moved into the the backlog of the VS Code team at Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115998#issuecomment-793294798), so you should see it arrive as a feature in the near future.

Comment: Yay! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Sad news: "We closed this issue because we don't plan to address it in the foreseeable future. If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: we are happy to listen and to reconsider." https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115998#issuecomment-1338226576